# My PL/SQL code is not working:

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log(repname in varchar2) AS 
  PACKAGE_NAME VARCHAR2,
  START_TIME DATE, 
  END_TIME DATE,
  STATUS;

BEGIN

  SELECT PACKAGE_NAME ,PRCS_START_TIME ,PRCS_END_TIME,STATUS
  FROM CONTCL_OWNER.PROCESSLOG 
  WHERE PACKAGE_NAME LIKE REPNAME
  ORDER BY PRCS_START_TIME
  WHERE ROW_NUMBER <=7;
END;
```

it's giving me these errors:

> Error(2,60): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
>
> Error(3,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national character nchar
>
> Error(7,26): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "AND" when expecting one of the following: . ( , * @ % & - + ; / at for mod remainder rem asc desc || multiset

Comment: give error message.

Comment: You are missing an `into` clause to store the result of the select statement. Please read the manual for details and examples: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS00603 and your variable declaration is wrong as well, each line needs to end with a `;`. Again this is documented in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS210  And the `status` variable has no data type.

Comment: Also your caps lock is on ;)

Comment: You should use only one `WHERE` clause. like something this: `WHERE PACKAGE_NAME LIKE REPNAME And ROW_NUMBER <=7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log(repname in varchar2) AS    
PACKAGE_NAME VARCHAR2,-- give size here like varchar2(50) 
START_TIME DATE,    
END_TIME DATE,   
STATUS;

BEGIN

 SELECT 
PACKAGE_NAME ,
PRCS_START_TIME ,
PRCS_END_TIME,
STATUS

-- add into clause to assign selected --values in variables 

FROM CONTCL_OWNER.PROCESSLOG    
WHERE PACKAGE_NAME LIKE '%REPNAME%' 
And ROW_NUMBER <=7   ORDER BY PRCS_START_TIME ; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set serveroutput on;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Plog(p_repname CONTCL_OWNER.PROCESSLOG.PACKAGE_NAME%TYPE)
IS 
    CURSOR c_ctl IS
        SELECT PACKAGE_NAME    AS PNAME,
               PRCS_START_TIME AS PSTIME,
               PRCS_END_TIME   AS PETIME,
               STATUS
        FROM CONTCL_OWNER.PROCESSLOG 
        WHERE PACKAGE_NAME = p_repname
        AND ROWNUM <=7
        ORDER BY PRCS_START_TIME ASC;
BEGIN
    FOR v_ctl IN c_ctl LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_ctl.PNAME  || ' - ' || 
                             v_ctl.PSTIME || ' - ' ||
                             v_ctl.PETIME || ' - ' ||
                             v_ctl.STATUS);
    /* ....
       HERE YOUR CODE LINE BY LINE
       ....
       ....
    */
    END LOOP;
END Plog;
```

You cannot use 'SELECT * INTO ...' because your SELECT returns many rows.